# Не работает программа на Java

Tags: java

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Написал "камень, ножницы, бумага" на java. В итоге при запуске программа ничего не пишет, хотя все методы вызываются в методе main
'

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static int machineNumber;
    public static String machineWord;
    public static String userWord;

    public static void userWord(){
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner("Выберите: камень, ножницы или бумага");
        userWord = scanner.nextLine();
    }
    public static void random(){
        int max = 3;
        int min = 1;
        int diff = max - min;
        Random random = new Random();
        machineNumber = random.nextInt(diff+1);
        machineNumber += min;
    }
    public static void checkMachineNumber(){
        if (machineNumber == 1){
            machineWord = "камень";
        } if (machineNumber == 2){
            machineWord = "бумага";
        } if (machineNumber == 3){
            machineWord = "ножницы";
        }
    }
    public static void checkMachineAndUserWords(){
        if (machineWord.equals(userWord)){
            System.out.println("ничья");
            System.out.println("компьютер - "+ machineWord + ", вы - " + userWord);
        } if (machineWord.equals("камень") & userWord.equals("бумага")){
            System.out.println("вы выйграли");
            System.out.println("компьютер - "+ machineWord + ", вы - " + userWord);
        } if (machineWord.equals("бумага") & userWord.equals("камень")){
            System.out.println("вы проиграли");
            System.out.println("компьютер - "+ machineWord + ", вы - " + userWord);
        } if (machineWord.equals("ножницы") & userWord.equals("бумага")){
            System.out.println("вы проиграли");
            System.out.println("компьютер - "+ machineWord + ", вы - " + userWord);
        } if (machineWord.equals("бумага") & userWord.equals("ножницы")){
            System.out.println("вы выйграли");
            System.out.println("компьютер - "+ machineWord + ", вы - " + userWord);
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        userWord();
        random();
        checkMachineNumber();
        checkMachineAndUserWords();
    }
}
```

`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы неправильно понимаете смысл строки, передающейся в конструктор `Scanner`.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#Scanner(java.lang.String)

Comment: Спасибо, все заработало

Comment: @Shtefan Пожалуйста. Успехов. Знак "галочка" - слева от ответа.